# How do I create a copy of a read-only FloatBuffer?

Tags: buffer, floatbuffer

I'm trying to edit a buffer, but the inputted copy (original) is read-only. The result has the same values but acts differently from the original; I'm not sure what's different. Why might this be the case?

```
private FloatBuffer cloneBuffer(FloatBuffer original) {
    final ByteBuffer byteClone = (original.isDirect()) ?
            //multiplying by 4 and adding 3 so the capacity is the same         
            //when converted to FloatBuffer
            ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(original.capacity() *4 + 3) :
            ByteBuffer.allocate(original.capacity() * 4 + 3);

    final FloatBuffer clone = byteClone.asFloatBuffer();
    final FloatBuffer readOnlyCopy = original.asReadOnlyBuffer();

    readOnlyCopy.rewind();
    clone.put(readOnlyCopy);
    clone.position(original.position());
    clone.limit(original.limit());



    return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out--I just had to set the order to LITTLE_ENDIAN